# anything similar to solaris mdb debugger for linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, solaris

Mdb seems to have many useful facilities (stemming from the M=Modular) that are not available with gdb.

Comment: like what ? `gdb` is trivially extensible (it's got a scripting language), while `mdb` requires compiled plugins (the "modules") to provide anything outside the core functionality. Yes, there's a big set of these provided; yes, all of this _could_ be written / created for `gdb` as well. What exactly do you miss ?